# Trying to get a sum in the footer of SSRS Report Builder

Tags: reportbuilder

Im trying to modify a report to display a sum of a certain column in the footer.

I've got this code in the footer: `=Sum(Fields!Column04.Value, "DataSet_Result")`
But it only shows up in the report as #Error

[This is the column that I'd like to sum up in the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwRb2.jpg)

[The code that only gives #Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUPKL.jpg)

[Preview of the report, where I'd like to se the sum (6 in this case)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELfas.jpg)

Initially I had a problem with the Scope, but now that seems cleared so now it just seems like I'm doing something wrong with the coding.